# The most efficient way to get object with max value from list of objects

Tags: c#, max, min, lis

I have an object called entry. It has min and max in float and fileName in string. And those objects are stored in a list

```
List<Entry> minMaxList = new List<Entry>();
```

I need to find an object(s) with the highest value and with the minimum value alongside with its file name.

So if I have an array like this

```
       Entry1                    Entry2                  Entry3
min  max    filename        min  max    filename      min  max    filename
| 2 | 120 |  file1.txt |  | 2 | 150 |  file1.txt |  | 5 | 150 |  file1.txt |
```

I want to get that the objects with the lowest value are Entry1 and Entry2 and objects with the highest value are Entry2 and Entry3

I tried this:

```
var max =  minMaxList.Max(r => r.getMax())
```

which works good, but it returns me a single value, without any other information about where it came from. I need either the whole object, or at least the filenames in which this value is. I wonder if it can be done in a single command, or if I have to then iterate the list again and find all the entries base on the min and max selected earlier.

Comment: What are your performance constraints? Are the LINQ Max and Min extensions methods too slow? Are you going to perform this look-up more than once on the same data?

Comment: This is the last task that I will be performing only once in the program. LINQ should be fine.

Comment: maybe can be done in a simple command using aggregate.

Comment: did you implement getmax()??? and why did u bother implementing it

Comment: Why have you framed the question asking for a single statement, efficient answer, then accepted an answer which is neither?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always filter the enumerable instead of only letting the maximum value through:

```
var maxvalue = minMaxList.Max(w => w.getMax());
var maxitems = minmaxlist.Where(w => w.getMax() == maxvalue);
```

Comment: unlikely to be the most efficient way, depending on the intended meaning of efficient.

Comment: Academical. The alternative to two O(n) scans through the list is one scan O(n) and inserting "duplicates" of this max value into a list (another O(n)). Either way gives you the same O(2n) (which is the same as O(n)) and the alternative way also uses up memory at an O(n) rate.

Comment: Essentially, its less efficient but not exponentially so. In practice you are right, especially for a list of 3. However, the OP did ask for the "most efficient",  ...

Comment: For what its worth, I reduced the memory allocation on my answer.

Comment: Did you? You're using *five* arrays read randomly, as opposed to one single array read sequentially that can most likely fit in your L1/L2 cache.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to add a filter that finds the matching items:

```
var max =  minMaxList.Max(r => r.getMax())

var itemsWithMax = minMaxList.Where(r => r.getMax() == max);
```

and similarly with `Min`.

> I wonder if it can be done in a single command

Probably, using complicated groupings or joins, but I would get something that *works* first and then try to make it *better* (remembering that a single query is not always "better" than multiple queries).

Comment: unlikely to be the most efficient way, depending on the intended meaning of efficient.

Comment: @Jodrell Fair enough - deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

you're asking about the most efficient way to solve this.

determinig the max / min value and searching those items afterwards requires to iterate the list twice. I would solve it manually in one loop

```
List<Entry> ResultList = new List<Entry>();
ResultList.Add(minMaxList[0]);
foreach (Entry item in minMaxList)
{
    if (item.getMax() >= ResultList[0].getMax())
    {
        if (item.getMax() != ResultList[0].getMax())
        {
            ResultList.Clear();
        }
        ResultList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a group by:

```
    var grpWithMaxVaues = minMaxList.GroupBy(c => c.getMax())
                                    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Key)
                                    .FirstOrDefault() 

        var max =   grpWithMaxVaues.FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(max.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be the shortest way.

```
var newList = new List<Hero>();
var maxValue = newList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Level).ToList()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think The most efficient way is using Aggregate.

```
var itemWithMax = minMaxList
    .Aggregate((current, next) => 
        current.getMax() > next.getMax() 
            ? current 
            : next
    );
```

Because it loops once over the list.
You can use .DefaultIfEmpty(null) for preventing empty list exception.

Comment: Current version of .NET has the `MaxBy` function which would be more simple.